# Build package for OSX when on Windows (Python 3.3, tkinter)

Tags: python

Given that the code has been written indepdently of platform, how do I build a package for MAC OS when I am on Windows and the package has been successfully built there? I can use `python setup.py bdist_msi` on windows, but not `python setup.py bdist_dmg`, since I am not on MAC. What to do about that?

Python 3.3, tkinter, cxFreeze, Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure OSX build tools (XCode et. al.) exist only on Apple platforms and there is no business rationale why Apple would have ported them to Windows.

So the probable answer is "buy Mac".

Comment: There has to be another way... The code should be completely platform independent...

Comment: I am sorry, but you are making false assumptions http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#bdist-dmg

Comment: What are you referring to? I don't get it? I am talking about that the python code should work, if only I could use cxFreeze on a mac using the exact same code. I find it weird that if it would run on any platform this code, then why is there no weird way of creating a .dmg from windows?